# angular 2 resolver for every view

Tags: angular, content-management-system, angular-cli, resolver

So my application is based on angular 2(angular cli) and some CMS. Some fragments of page are downloaded from CMS and displayed on angular 2 page. The main problem is that the header and footer are from CMS. 
So I wonder how to add global resolver(global is very important, I dont want to add resolver for every route path in application), that will force angular to wait till CMS will return header and footer. I am already successfully using resolver to wait for some data on some routes by implementing route interface

```
export class InboxResolver implements Resolve<MessageListItem[]>
```

and I am using it in some custom routes:

```
const MessagesRoutes: Routes = [
 {
    path: 'inbox',
    component: InboxComponent,
    resolve: { messages: InboxResolver }
 }
];
```

But how to define one global HeaderAndFooterResolver in one place?

Comment: As far as I know, doing what you are asking is not possible. One solution is to add a function to the resolver that checks whether or not the data is already loaded - this will at least prevent duplicate calls, you will still need a resolver on every route though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not sure what your question is about but you can use a componentless parent route with a resolver and share this with all its child routes

```
const MessagesRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', resolve: { messages: InboxResolver }, children: [
        { path: 'inbox', component: InboxComponent},
        { path: 'xxx', component: XxxComponent},
        { path: 'zzz', component: XxxComponent},
    ]}
];
```

Comment: Yup, I am trying something similar like u said. But parent route includes component app.template.component which is using TemplateResolver aka inboxResolver which fetch header and footer from CMS. So to sum up, idea atm is to create app parent route, so every other route must be its child. So this resolver would be resolver for every route in application since every route is child route of app template route

Comment: Yes, every route needs to be a child route of this route, or you add the resolver to each route.

Comment: Seems kind of dirty, but I don't have a better solution and it's an idea. Maybe some sort of non-router guard solution?

Comment: The approach with the resolver on the componentless parent route is a suggestion by the router developer from the Angular team.

Answer (score 4):

You basically need one `resolver` for each `component` and need to be declare once for each route, unless they are parent > child, you can share the resolver between them like below:

```
const MessagesRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', resolve: { messages: EmailResolver }, children: [
    { path: 'inbox', component: InboxComponent },
    { path: 'outbox', component: OutboxComponent },
    { path: 'sent', component: SentComponent },
    { path: 'received', component: ReceivedComponent }
  ]}
];
```

Answer (score 3):

Provided you just want to add the resolver to every top level route then something like the below would do it.

```
   const addGlobalResolver = <T extends Type<Resolve<any>>>(routePaths: Routes, resolver: T, name: string): Routes => {
      return routePaths.map(route => {
        if (route.resolve != null || route.resolve === undefined) {
          route.resolve = {};
        }
        route.resolve[name] = resolver;
        return route;
      });
    };
```

Just invoke it before you pass the routes to the routing module.

```
[RouterModule.forRoot(addGlobalResolver(routes, InjuryResolver, 'Injury'))]
```